# ios - keep track of views with dismiss(modal)View

Tags: objective-c, ios, dismiss, uistoryboardsegue, multiple-views

I am trying to have a number (UILabel) to be send to another UIViewController.

Now I am able to go one way, but I also need to bring the result back to the initial Controller when I return to that.

On top of that I am trying to do this with 4 UILabel's so I need to distinguish between them.

Now to get to the 2nd ViewController I want to use a segue like this:

```
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ChangeNumberSegue"])
{
    NSLog(@"Changing the Number on NumberPadViewController");

    NumberPadViewController *numberPad = segue.destinationViewController;

    if(_BtnNumber01)
    {
        numberPad.numberLine.text = _LblNumber01.text;
    }
    if(_BtnNumber02)
    {
        numberPad.numberLine.text = _LblNumber02.text;
    }
    if(_BtnNumber03)
    {
        numberPad.numberLine.text = _LblNumber03.text;
    }
    if(_BtnNumber04)
    {
        numberPad.numberLine.text = _LblNumber04.text;
    }
}
```

The question is: What is the correct way to dismiss the 2nd view once I am done with it.
Once I am in the second view it will only change the number of the selected label.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a modal segue...

In lieu of an actual return value, just create a property in the first view controller that you want set, such as:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger theValue;
```

Inside the second view controller, you can get a handle to the first such as:

```
FirstViewController *vc = (FirstViewController *) [self presentingViewController];
vc.theValue = 5;
```

As far as returning back to the original view controller, you can add this inside your second view controller:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // iOS 6
// or
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; // iOS 5 or earlier
```